# Why can't I move a window below the dock?

Tags: macos, window-manager

I'm trying to move a window so that I can see part of the title at the top of the dock, basically the text in between where the individual icons on the dock stick up.  I am fine with this as basically it is an e-mail window, and all I want is the ability to glance over and see the status in the title.

So I position the window where I want it, but as soon as I let go, it jumps up about two tenths of an inch so that the title is entirely above the dock.  This is unacceptable, as I already have another window that extends down to the top of the dock, so when I switch back to that window (which is normal operation) the title is now completely hidden.

I've got a 27" iMac, so the Dock is not as wide as the whole screen, and there is plenty of space for me to grab the window even if part of it was completely overlaid by the dock.  So it's not as if by putting the window here I wouldn't be able to get it back.

Is there some preference option of something to force OS X to obey my instructions on where to place the window?

Comment: I doubt there is a way to do this. Why not just minimize the window into the dock? Then you can mouse over it to see the title when you need it.

Comment: The image of the window in the dock doesn't update if contents of the minimized window changes, does it?  That would be a useful feature if, for example, the window contained a video feed and you wanted to watch for something that would be obvious at that scale (for instance, going from a black image to an actual feed when lights were turned on.)

Comment: True, but I thought the issue was that you wanted to be able to see the window title. If you minimize the window, the title will appear on mouseover and it'll update if the window's title changes.

Comment: Yeah, it is.  But it occurred to me that if the window where to display information large enough that a change would show up in the icon, that would eliminate the need to mouse over it.